# grep to get all the getters from a java file

Tags: shell, scripting, grep

I have a java file called Friends.java . There are 5 variables and each variable has its own getter. Assume that all the functions below follow standard java standard, i.e

```
public methodName(){
//Some code here;
}
```

Here is the file `Friends.java`

```
//Variables
int numberOfFriends;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String address;
boolean isWorker;
//Methods
Friends();
int getNumberOfFriends(){
//Some Code here;
}
public String getFirstName(){
//Some Code here;
}
public String getLastName(){
//Some Code here;
}
public String getAddress(){
//Some Code here;
}
private String getIsWorker(){
//Some Code here;
}
public String toString(){
    return getNumberOfFriends + " " + getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + " " + getAddress() + " " + getIsWorker() + " ";
}
```

I want to grep through this file to get a list of all the getters. 
This is what I have so far :

```
grep "get*{$" Friends.java
```

But I do not get any result.

Comment: There are almost certainly *much* better tools for this than `grep`; searching [so] will surely yield a few Java introspection tools.

Comment: There is no guarantee that { (or even () ) are on the same line as the name of the function.

Comment: @user39428 as per as java formatting standards they should be in the same line. I have also mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it correctly, then this should do:

```
grep "^get.*();$" Friends.java
```

**EDIT:** Answer to the edited question:

```
$ grep -o "get.*{$" Friends.java
getNumberOfFriends(){
getFirstName(){
getLastName(){
getAddress(){
getIsWorker(){
```

Comment: Please check the edited question..

Answer (score 1):

`grep` uses regular expressions; so

```
grep "get*{$" Friends.java
```

matches lines with 'g', 'e', followed by zero or more 't's (`t*`), followed by '{' at the end of a line. You need to specify the generic character for the repeating operator:

```
grep "get.*{$" Friends.java
```